# Invalid java home in weblogic installation macos

Tags: java, weblogic-10.x

The error appear when I select the jdk directory at the /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home

[image]

And this is my java version.

[image]

So, I have to change the JAVA_HOME to 1.6.0.jdk or not?
This version of weblogic installer is 10.3.6, I try to search and found that this weblogic version can support the java6, but why I cannot choose the 1.6.0.jdk directory? Or have something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem I just run terminal with `java -Dos.name="OS X" -Dspace.detection=false -jar <filename>.jar`